# Azure AD Guest users can't login

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I have sent an invitation to a user with the email address of "fakePerson@em.com"

But, apparently this user signs into their computer with "email/fakePerson"

They are experiencing a problem where they cannot accept the invite and/or sign in. When they are first prompted after clicking the invite link, it tells them "Your email or password is incorrect. If you don't remember your password, reset it now." (And of course since it COSTS to allow users to reset their passwords we don't allow them to do so...)

And in the old sign-in experience we get: "We don't recognize this user ID or password"

What is causing this?  Is it because their domain is different than the domain part of their email address? ex: `em != email`

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what the issue is but don't you need to add the guest users to the list of users, under Azure Active Directory > Users and Groups > All Users > New User, in order for them to be able to login?

Comment: I've done that. Only instead of "New Users" - I used "New Guest User" which sends them an invite email. They then click a button in that email and it takes them through a MS "acceptance" process to sign them up for our AAD.  This works like 90% of the time, but for the 10% it doesn't - it's insanely frustrating.

Comment: Oh I see, have you tried changing the Guest User access permissions? AZURE PORTAL: Azure Active Directory > Users and Groups > User Settings > External users - Set 'Guest users permissions are limited' to 'No' also try MANAGEMENT PORTAL: Active Directory > Select 'YourTenant' > Configure(tab along the top) > Scroll down to User Access > Set 'LIMIT GUEST ACCESS' to 'NO'

Comment: It's not about the difference of email address . Since you've invited the user as a guest user, it can use any email address. However , you need to login Azure with email address, not `domain\username`. 

After inviting , go to your guest user's email and click `Get Started`. Then you click `Next` in the webpage, Just wait the browse to `refresh`, it would let your set your new password.

Comment: @WayneYang-MSFT I did try sending an invite to their email as if the full domain was correct. So I sent it to fakePerson@email.com because they login to their PC with email\fakePerson. I did that thinking it may trick the MS login or something...  what happened then is more of what you described... it seems to allow them to create a new password. The problem with this tho is...my app actually needs to use their real email address to send them emails. So that won’t work. When I send an invite to their real email/ fakePerson@em.com, it doesn’t allow them to make a new password. Only says “wrong”

Comment: You need to use their email address to login as a guest user. Also, if you have already invited a account to Azure AD, you need to reset the password from Azure portal.

Comment: The reset password feature is greyed out and unusable. Lol, you actually have to pay an additional fee to be able to reset peoples password OR EVEN let them reset their own passwords!!! Totally insane. And we don’t pay for that so it isn’t an option unfortunately....

Comment: Reset password feature doesn't need further payment. Go to Azure portal> Azure Active Directory >All users > select the user > you would see the Rest password bottom. If yours is grey out, you may not have enough permissions.

Comment: I will double check that then. The account I am using is an administrative account... I believe we have no other account with higher permissions in our Azure subscription than this account but I will try.

Comment: @WayneYang-MSFT so, what specifically, can I check regarding my administrative account's permissions?  I still cannot reset a guest user's password.